# Add content type to lists in all subsites programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, office365

Honestly, I'm new to office 365 development.

I want to add existing content type to all lists in all sub-sites in the site collection after clicking a button in the page. I'll try to do with the sandbox solution accessing all lists through the JavaScript, but I am unable to find a way to do that.

I would appreciate if someone can help me figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        var contentTypeCollection;
        var contentType;
        var listCollection;
        var list;
        var listContentTypeColl;

        function addExistingContentTypetoList() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                var web = clientContext.get_web();
                this.contentTypeCollection = web.get_contentTypes();
                this.contentType = contentTypeCollection.getById("0x0100FFC434A461E47E4EB81D3FD76D42BFBF");
                this.listCollection = web.get_lists();
                this.list = listCollection.getByTitle("List Request");
                this.listContentTypeColl = list.get_contentTypes();
                this.listContentTypeColl.addExistingContentType(contentType);
                clientContext.load(this.listContentTypeColl);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
            }
        } 
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
alert('Content Type added successfully');
                    } 
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Suggestion, use [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)